# Grouping based on sequence of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a table of orders with a column denoting whether it's a buy or a sell, with the rows typically ordered by timestamp.  What I'd like to do is operate on groups of consecutive buys, plus their sell.  e.g. `B B S B S B B S -> (B B S) (B S) (B B S)`

Example:

```
order_action |      timestamp      
-------------+---------------------
buy          | 2013-10-03 13:03:02
buy          | 2013-10-08 13:03:02
sell         | 2013-10-10 15:58:02
buy          | 2013-11-01 09:30:02
buy          | 2013-11-01 14:03:02
sell         | 2013-11-07 10:34:02
buy          | 2013-12-03 15:46:02
sell         | 2013-12-09 16:00:03
buy          | 2013-12-11 13:02:02
sell         | 2013-12-18 15:59:03
```

I'll be running an aggregation function in the end (the groups are so that I can exclude an entire group based on its sell order), so `GROUP BY` or partitioned windows seemed like the right way to go, but I can't figure out how to get this specific grouping.

Comment: If you have any attempts, please post your code

Comment: Can you add a sample of the output you would like to see?

Comment: Will every group of buys only have one sell?

Comment: `What I'd like to do is operate on groups of consecutive buys...` What is `operate`? That is, what do you actually want to **do**? And what problem are you having with doing it? It's tricky suggesting solutions for undefined problems.

Comment: I've asked a similar question before, it may be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889056/finding-a-run-of-rows-from-an-ordered-result-set

Answer (score 4):

This can be ***surprisingly simple*** with `count()` as window aggregate function:

#### **Postgres 9.4** or later with aggregate `FILTER`:

```sql
SELECT *, count(*) FILTER (WHERE order_action = 'sell')
                   OVER (ORDER BY ts DESC) AS grp
FROM   orders
ORDER  BY ts;
```

Or with ascending `grp` numbers:

```sql
SELECT *, count(*) FILTER (WHERE order_action = 'sell')
          OVER (ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS grp
FROM   orders
ORDER  BY ts;
```

See:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

Using `ts` instead as `timestamp` as column name to avoid [reserved words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) as identifiers.

`count()` returns a running count with [the default frame definition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) from the start of the frame (the whole table in this case) up to the (last peer of) the current row. The running count of sells groups your rows as requested.
I am ordering *descending* in the `OVER` clause to let each group end at a trailing "sell", not a leading "sell". This results in descending group numbers. But that should not matter, you just needed group numbers.
Duplicate timestamps would be a problem (in any case!).

One way for **ascending group numbers**: use a custom [`FRAME` definition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) for the window function:

#### In any Postgres version

```sql
SELECT *, count(order_action = 'sell' OR NULL) OVER (ORDER BY ts DESC) AS grp
FROM   orders
ORDER  BY ts;
```

```sql
SELECT *, count(order_action = 'sell' OR NULL)
          OVER (ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS grp
FROM   orders;
```

`count()` only counts non-null values. The expression `order_action = 'sell' OR NULL` results in `TRUE` for 'sell' and `NULL` otherwise.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6d30006aad10c37086b26c40111160cf)* - demonstrating all.
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6b46d/4)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I don't have PostgreSQL, so i tried this over on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4a14d/42)

```
with sells as (
  select
    rank() over w grp,
    lag(timestamp,1,'2000-01-01') over w sd,
    timestamp td
  from
    orders
  where
    order_action = 'sell'
  window w as (order by timestamp)
)
select
  s.grp,
  o.order_action,
  o.timestamp
from
  orders o
join
  sells s
    on o.timestamp > s.sd
    and o.timestamp <= s.td
order by o.timestamp
```

Let me know if this works for you. This was my first time using PostgreSQL and I like it.

Answer (score 1):

You can characterize the groups by counting the number of `sell`s at or later than each row.  You can do this with a cumulative sum to get the group that can then be used for aggregation.  Here is an example:

```
select min(timestamp), max(timestamp), sum(case when order_action = 'buy' then 1 else 0 end) as buys
from (select o.*,
             sum(case when order_action = 'sell' then 1 else 0 end) over
                 (order by timestamp desc) as grp
      from orders o
     ) o
group by grp
```