# Reduce results into accumulated groups

Tags: sql, postgresql, grouping, window-functions

Having the following table (describing a conversation):

```
 id | record_id  |  is_response  |         text         |
 ---+------------+---------------+----------------------+
 1  |     1      |      false    | first line of text   |
 2  |     1      |      true     | second line of text  |
 3  |     1      |      false    | third line of text   |
 4  |     1      |      true     | fourth line of text  |
 5  |     1      |      true     | fifth line of text   |
 6  |     2      |      false    | first line of text   |
 7  |     2      |      true     | second line of text  |
 8  |     2      |      false    | third line of text   |
 9  |     2      |      true     | fourth line of text  |
 10 |     2      |      true     | fifth line of text   |
```

I'm looking for an SQL query to output the following:

```
  record_id |       in_text         |         out_text
  ----------+-----------------------+---------------------
       1    | first line of text    | second line of text
  ----------+-----------------------+---------------------
       1    | first line of text    | 
            | second line of text   | 
            | third line of text    | fourth line of text
  ----------+-----------------------+---------------------
       1    | first line of text    |  
            | second line of text   | 
            | third line of text    | 
            | fourth line of text   | fifth line of text
  ----------+-----------------------+---------------------
       2    | first line of text    | second line of text
  ----------+-----------------------+---------------------
       2    | first line of text    | 
            | second line of text   | 
            | third line of text    | fourth line of text
  ----------+-----------------------+---------------------
       2    | first line of text    | 
            | second line of text   | 
            | third line of text    | 
            | fourth line of text   | fifth line of text
```

Meaning each time `is_response` column is `true` accumulate the text column as the `in_text` and add the new row as `out_text`.

The order of rows is defined by `id`.

Is it possible using pure SQL? How?

Comment: But, since `id` is not UNIQUE, there *must* be another key element ...

Comment: You seem to assume a natural order of rows, which does not exist in relational DB tables. You need some way to order rows, Postgres does not know that "first line of text" should come first.

Comment: Does it matter for the solution? if so I'll change id to record_id and add another column

Comment: Please check my edits (added a primary column)

Comment: Yes: it matters (not only for the solution) A table without a candidate key is basically useless.

Comment: Sure, I've just added a primary key to the example

Comment: I have this weird feeling, that you try to solve an entirely different problem and assume this would be the way. This could be absolutely true of course, but I'm reluctant to wrap my hand around this particular question. Why would you want such a thing?

Comment: I took the liberty to adjust the desired result to your changed setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the aggregate function `string_agg()` as window function in a subquery:

```
SELECT record_id, in_text, out_text  
FROM  (
   SELECT record_id, text AS out_text, is_response
        , string_agg(text, E'\n')
          OVER (PARTITION BY record_id ORDER BY id
                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS in_text
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
WHERE  is_response;
```

The special feature here is to adjust the window frame with a `ROWS` clause. Related:

- [Grouping based on sequence of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708067/grouping-based-on-sequence-of-rows/24709377#24709377)

[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bff53/1) (Line breaks are converted to spaces in sqlfiddle.)

Comment: Works like a charm :)

Comment: could you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577026/postgres-select-partitions-based-on-matches/39583041#39583041 the answer is almost complete, but fails to aggregate single reponses, tahnks :)