# Select partitions based on matches in other table

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

Having the following table (`conversations`):

```
 id | record_id  |  is_response  |         text         |
 ---+------------+---------------+----------------------+
 1  |     1      |      false    | in text 1            |
 2  |     1      |      true     | response text 3      |
 3  |     1      |      false    | in text 2            |
 4  |     1      |      true     | response text 2      |
 5  |     1      |      true     | response text 3      |
 6  |     2      |      false    | in text 1            |
 7  |     2      |      true     | response text 1      |
 8  |     2      |      false    | in text 2            |
 9  |     2      |      true     | response text 3      |
 10 |     2      |      true     | response text 4      |
```

And another help table (`responses`):

```
 id |         text         |
 ---+----------------------+
 1  | response text 1      |
 2  | response text 2      |
 3  | response text 4      |
```

I'm looking for an SQL query to output the following:

```
  record_id |       context
  ----------+-----------------------+---------------------
       1    | in text 1 response text 3 in text 2 response text 2
  ----------+-----------------------+---------------------
       2    | in text 1 response text 1
  ----------+-----------------------+---------------------
       2    | in text 2 response text 3 response text 4
```

So each time `is_response` is `true` and the `text` is **in** the responses table, **aggregate** the conversation context up to this point, ignoring conversation part that does not end with a response in the pool.

In the example above living *response text 3* in `record_id` 1.

I've tried the following complex SQL but it breaks sometimes aggregating the text wrong:

```
with context as(
    with answers as (

       SELECT record_id, is_response, id as ans_id
        , max(id)
          OVER (PARTITION BY record_id ORDER BY id
          ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS previous_ans_id
       FROM (select * from conversations where text in (select text from responses)) ans
       ),
     lines as (
      select answers.record_id, con.id, COALESCE(previous_ans_id || ',' || ans_id, '0') as block, con.text as text from answers, conversations con where con.engagement_id = answers.record_id and ((previous_ans_id is null and con.id <= ans_id) OR (con.id > previous_ans_id and con.id <= ans_id)) order by engagement_id, id asc
      )

      select record_id, block,replace(trim(both ' ' from string_agg(text, E' ')) ,'  ',' ') ctx from lines group by record_id, block order by record_id,block
      )

select * from context
```

I'm sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take:

```
SELECT
    record_id,
    string_agg(text, ' ' ORDER BY id) AS context
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        coalesce(sum(incl::integer) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),0) AS grp
    FROM (
        SELECT *, is_response AND text IN (SELECT text FROM responses) as incl
        FROM conversations
         ) c
     ) c1
GROUP BY record_id, grp
HAVING bool_or(incl)
ORDER BY max(id);
```

This will scan the table `conversations` once, but I am not sure if it will perform better than your solution. The basic idea is to use a window function to count how maybe preceding rows within the same record, end the conversation. Then we can group by with that number and the `record_id` and discard incomplete conversations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately in your solution the aggregated text does not preserve the ordering of the lines, and I get  the text and responses mixed up

Comment: @ShlomiSchwartz I added an `ODER BY` in the aggregate, it should be ok now.

Comment: Works like a charm. Wasn't familiar with ordering within the aggregate function. Thank you.

Comment: What if I wanted to change the query, so when incl field is true in sequence (F,F,F,T,T,T) the text will be aggregated in the same group and not as a stand alone row?

Comment: @ShlomiSchwartz I am not sure I understand what you mean. Do you want to do the aggregation only in places where incl is true _and_ the record that follows has incl=false?

Comment: your query works great, except when there more than one valid response in a row. While the desired output is to join them, this query gives 2 groups. In the example above there is the desired output for this scenario (`in text 2 response text 3 response text 4`).

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple and fast solution:

```
SELECT record_id, string_agg(text, ' ') As context
FROM  (
   SELECT c.*, count(r.text) OVER (PARTITION BY c.record_id ORDER BY c.id DESC) AS grp
   FROM   conversations  c
   LEFT   JOIN responses r ON r.text = c.text AND c.is_response
   ORDER  BY record_id, id
   ) sub
WHERE  grp > 0  -- ignore conversation part that does not end with a response
GROUP  BY record_id, grp
ORDER  BY record_id, grp;
```

`count()` only counts non-null values. `r.text` is NULL if the `LEFT JOIN` to `responses` comes up empty:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

The value in `grp` (short for "group") is only increased when a new output row is triggered. All rows belonging to the same output row end up with the same `grp` number. It's then easy to aggregate in the outer `SELECT`.

The special trick is to count conversation *ends* in reverse order. Everything after the last *end* (coming first when starting from the end) gets `grp = 0` and is removed in the outer `SELECT`.

Similar cases with more explanation:

- [Row number with reset in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149519/row-number-with-reset-in-postgresql/149600#149600)
- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/select-longest-continuous-sequence/35389#35389)