# Selecting and averaging previous values of a row

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

There is a portion of the SQL query that fetches a value from the previous row.

```
...
lag(rs.processed_value, 1) OVER (
  PARTITION BY rs.rloi_id, rs.qualifier
  ORDER BY rs.rloi_id, rs.qualifier, rs.timestamp
) AS previous_value,
rs.parent_rank FROM rs WHERE rs.parent_rank = ANY (
  ARRAY[1::bigint, 2::bigint]
)
...
```

| roi_id | qualifier | processed_value | previous_value | parent_rank | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | STAGE | 0.76 | NULL | 2 | 2023-01-04 |
| 1001 | STAGE | 0.78 | 0.76 | 1 | 2023-01-05 |
| 1001 | STAGE | 0.66 | NULL | 2 | 2021-01-04 |
| 1001 | STAGE | 0.68 | 0.66 | 1 | 2021-01-05 |

What I would like to do now is fetch the previous 4 rows (`parent_rank`'s 2-5), `SUM() and divide them by 4` to get an average, and return that as the `previous_value`.

I am able to return the previous 4 values by increasing the `ARRAY` section of the query.

```
...
rs.parent_rank FROM rs WHERE rs.parent_rank = ANY (
  ARRAY[1::bigint, 2::bigint, 3::bigint, 4::bigint, 5::bigint]
)
...
```

| roi_id | processed_value | previous_value | parent_rank | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 0.70 | NULL | 5 | 2023-01-01 |
| 1001 | 0.72 | 0.70 | 4 | 2023-01-02 |
| 1001 | 0.74 | 0.72 | 3 | 2023-01-03 |
| 1001 | 0.76 | 0.74 | 2 | 2023-01-04 |
| 1001 | 0.78 | 0.76 | 1 | 2023-01-05 |
| 1001 | 0.60 | NULL | 5 | 2021-01-01 |
| 1001 | 0.62 | 0.60 | 4 | 2021-01-02 |
| 1001 | 0.64 | 0.62 | 3 | 2021-01-03 |
| 1001 | 0.66 | 0.64 | 2 | 2021-01-04 |
| 1001 | 0.68 | 0.66 | 1 | 2021-01-05 |

The desired outcome is to have the `previous_value` for rows of `parent_rank = 1`, to be the new averaged value.

**Desired outcome**

| roi_id | processed_value | previous_value | parent_rank | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 0.76 | NULL | 2 | 2023-01-04 |
| 1001 | 0.78 | **0.73*** | 1 | 2023-01-05 |
| 1001 | 0.66 | NULL | 2 | 2021-01-04 |
| 1001 | 0.68 | **0.63*** | 1 | 2021-01-05 |

(*the averaged value)

**Portion of the query**

```
WITH ranked_all_value_summaries AS (
    SELECT tvp.rloi_id,
        tv.processed_value,
        tv.timestamp,
        tv.error,
        rank() OVER (PARTITION BY tvp.rloi_id, tvp.qualifier ORDER BY tv.timestamp DESC, tv.telemetry_value_id DESC) AS parent_rank
        FROM sls_telemetry_value tv
        JOIN sls_telemetry_value_parent tvp ON tv.telemetry_value_parent_id = tvp.telemetry_value_parent_id
            WHERE lower(tvp.parameter) = 'water level'::text
            AND lower(tvp.units) !~~ '%deg%'::text
            AND lower(tvp.qualifier) !~~ '%height%'::text
            AND lower(tvp.qualifier) <> 'crest tapping'::text
    ),
    latest_value_summaries_with_previous_value AS (
        SELECT ranked_all_value_summaries.rloi_id,
            ranked_all_value_summaries.qualifier,
            ranked_all_value_summaries.processed_value,
            ranked_all_value_summaries.timestamp,
            lag(ranked_all_value_summaries.processed_value, 1) OVER (
                PARTITION BY ranked_all_value_summaries.rloi_id, ranked_all_value_summaries.qualifier
                    ORDER BY ranked_all_value_summaries.rloi_id, ranked_all_value_summaries.qualifier, ranked_all_value_summaries.timestamp
            ) AS previous_value
            ranked_all_value_summaries.parent_rank FROM ranked_all_value_summaries WHERE ranked_all_value_summaries.parent_rank = ANY (
                ARRAY[1::bigint, 2::bigint, 3::bigint, 4::bigint, 5::bigint]
            )
  ) SELECT * FROM latest_value_summaries_with_previous_value;
```

Comment: Please show a **complete** (minimal) query, the underlying table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement), and the sample data as `INSERT` script. Ideally, add a fiddle to work with. And always your Postgres version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can adjust the [window frame](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) and just use `avg()`:

```sql
    avg(rs.processed_value OVER (PARTITION BY rs.rloi_id, rs.qualifier
                                 ORDER BY rs.timestamp
                                 ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)  -- !
```

You don't need to repeat columns listed in the `PARTITION` clause in the `ORDER BY` clause.

It's unclear what the result should be when there are fewer than 4 previous rows available.

Related:

- [Grouping based on sequence of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708067/grouping-based-on-sequence-of-rows/24709377#24709377)

Comment: This has worked. Thank you for this, much appreciated